# Ищу библиотеку .NET для работы с PDF

Tags: .net, pdf

Необходимы следующие возможности:

- Конвертация различных форматов в PDF: HTML, Word (doc/x), Excel
  (xls/x), картинки (jpeg, tiff).
- работа с Office форматами без установленного Office
- Split-Merge документов

Из необязательного:

- произвольная генерация PDF
- Просмотр PDF - PDF-Viewer
- извлечение текста/каринок
- можно комерческие решения

На что стоит посмотреть?

Comment: Уважаемые голосующие за закрытие, будьте добры оставлять комментарии автору вопроса, чтобы он понимал, в чём вы видите проблему.

Comment: @VladD я вообще тут не понимаю позицию закрывальщиков. Четко описаны требования к библиотеке. Ну какой опросник? На многие вопросы по проектированию тоже не может быть дан однозначно правильный ответ, но тем не менее это нормальные вопросы, к которым даются нормальные ответы.

Answer (score 1):

В `"Управление пакетами NuGet"` по запросу pdf, отображается замечательная библиотека от `Apitron`, так же для pdf есть библиотека от `ABC`, опять же ни-кто не отменял библиотеки самого `Adobe Acrobat`. Вопрос просто цены использования. Если нужно что то, вроде GNU или GPL тогда стоит подумать о `Ghostscript`. Для офиса, как уже говорили, стоит взглянуть в сторону `OpenOffice`.

Answer (score 1):

[iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) - хорошая библиотека! Но всех перечисленных задач она не выполнмит.

[docx](http://docx.codeplex.com/)

[UseOffice .Net](http://www.sautinsoft.com/convert-rtf-html-doc-docx-xls-xlsx-ppt-to-pdf-net-library/overview.php)

[Aspose](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/11338)

Answer (score 0):

Можно посмотреть на библиотеку [PdfSharp](http://pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/). Библиотека для генерации pdf в .Net.
[Здесь](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Projects/PDFsharp-MigraDoc-GDI) находится документация в читаемом виде.

Работа с office возможна в .Net из коробки. Необходимо добавить библиотеку вида Microsoft.Office.Interop.*.dll (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll для Excel соответственно) в зависимости проекта.

Скорее всего для конвертации форматов в PDF придётся их предварительно парсить.

Comment: По-моему возможность работы с `office` в `.Net` доступна не из коробки, для этого надо устанавливать `Microsoft Office Developer Tools` либо отдельно, либо при первоначальной установке. Но даже подключение этих библиотек при разработке, не снимет с клиента обязанности установки `office` чтобы приложение, написанное с использованием этих com объектов стало доступным

Comment: Если вы добавляете dll в references, то dll будет лежать вместе с приложением.

Comment: На сколько я в курсе, добавление этих референсов и dll в приложение, лишь позволяет использовать возможности и функции приложений MSOffice в программе, но не даёт возможности использования приложения без установленного Office. Исходя из текста представленного на [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57.aspx) `To use the features of a Microsoft Office application from an Office project, you must use the primary interop assembly (PIA) for the application. The PIA enables managed code to interact with a Microsoft Office application's COM-based object model.`

Comment: Как я понимаю: мы добавляем dll и при компиляции она попадает в сборку. Это даёт нам возможность создавать в приложении файлы MS Office. Логично что для открытия такого файла на клиентской машине необходимо иметь установленный MS Office. Но в приложении с помощью той же dll мы можем парсить файл MS Office и выводить пользователю. Поправьте меня, пожалуйста, если я ошибаюсь.

Comment: При чтении, запускается процесс того или иного приложения office и соответственно чтобы поработать или получить данные или сконвертировать их в pdf необходим сам office. Библиотеки референса содержат лишь инструкции как работать с office, но не сами функциональные возможности, насколько мне известно.

Comment: Про PIA офисных библиотек мне известно. Требование - работа без установленного офиса. Так что - отпадает.